# Populating async array with a function called right before.

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var request = require('request'),
requests = [],
values = [],

request("url1", function());

function() {
.....
  for (x in list){
   requests.push(requestFunction(x));
  }
}

requestFunction(x){
  request("url2", function (e,r,b) {
    ....
    return function(callback) {
    values[i] = b
    }
  });
}

async.parallel(requests, function (allResults) {
    // values array is ready at this point
    // the data should also be available in the allResults array
    console.log(values);
});
```

I new to node. Issue is that the request needs to be called to populate the requests callback array. But the issue is the async.parallel will run before the requests array is full and need run all the callbacks. Where do I move this async so it runs after the requests array is full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous programming is all about chaining blocks. This allows node to efficiently run its event queue, while ensuring that your steps are done in order. For example, here's a query from a web app I wrote:

```
app.get("/admin", isLoggedIn, isVerified, isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    User.count({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) throw err;
        User.count({"verified.isVerified" : true}, function (err2, verifiedUsers) {
            if (err2) throw err2;
            Course.count({}, function (err3, courses) {
                // and this continues on and on — the admin page
                // has a lot of information on all the documents in the database
            })
        })
    })  
})
```

Notice how I chained function calls inside of one another. `Course.count({}, ...)` could only be called once `User.count({"verified.isVerified" : true}, ...)` was called. This means the i/o is never blocked and the `/admin` page is never rendered without the required information.

You didn't really give enough information regarding your problem (so there might be a better way to fix it), but I think you could, for now, do this:

```
var request = require('request'),
    requests = [],
    values = [],
    length;     // a counter to store the number of times to run the loop

request("url1", function() {

    length = Object.keys(list).length;
    // referring to the list below;
    // make sure list is available at this level of scope

    for (var x in list){
        requests.push(requestFunction(x));
        length--;
        if (length == 0) {
            async.parallel(requests, function (allResults) {
                console.log(values);    // prints the values array
            });
        }
    }
}

function requestFunction(x) {
    request("url2", function (e,r,b) {
        values[i] = b;
        return b;
    }
}
```

I am assuming that `requestFunction()` takes a while to load, which is why `async.parallel` is running before the `for (var x in list)` loop finishes. To force `async.parallel` to run after the loop finishes, you'll need a counter.

```
var length = Object.keys(list).length;
```

This returns the number of keys in the `list` associative array (aka object). Now, every time you run through the for loop, you decrement `length`. When `length == 0`, you then run your `async.parallel` process.

**edit:** You could also write the `requests.push()` part as:

```
requests.push(
    (function () {
        request("url2", function (e,r,b) {
            values[i] = b;
            return b;
        }
    })()
);
```

I think it's redundant to store `b` in both `values` and `requests`, but I have kept it as you had it.

Comment: Thats very helpful. I'm having an issue now were the requests array is undefined. Am I returning the function incorrectly in requestFunction?

Comment: @CWon Is this for a specific library? Regardless, `requestFunction` doesn't really make sense. You return a function: `return function(callback) { … }`, but that lambda doesn't return anything.

Comment: @CWon I changed the `requestFunction` in my original answer and have added another method for pushing to the `requests` array.